# Why doesn't the nohup command seem to be working?

Tags: linux, rhel, nohup

Please let me know any example that shows [`nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) is working for a program even after `logout`. I tried using it without the `nohup` command to run a script in the background and it seems to be working even after `logout`.

Example:

```
ping google.com > ping_result &
```

Then I log out and log in again, and I found the files' contents are getting incremented. It means that ping is still running. However, it should not.

Comment: that's exactly what `nohup` is for...

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in a terminal,

`/bin/sleep 1000 &`

In a different terminal, check the process is running:

`pgrep -fa sleep`
(process shown)

Now close the first terminal, or log out. Check again:

`pgrep -fa sleep`
(nothing shown)

Repeat the steps adding `nohup` to the first command:

`nohup /bin/sleep 1000 &`

You will see the second check shows the process still running.

Answer (score -1):

Well, here is one example. Type this:

`nohup find -size +100k > log.txt`

and logout. Then log in again and check the log.txt file.

More info: [Linux and Unix nohup command](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm)

Comment: if i will do  the same thing without the nohup like             find -size +100k > log.txt &                                      and log out and login again .does the same thing .so what is the use of nuhup ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595374/whats-the-difference-between-nohup-and-ampersand

Answer (score -1):

nohup doesn't "kill" (prevents signal hangup aka SIGHUP amd see man 7 signal) a process that tries to write to terminal when there is no terminal.

When a process doesn't write to terminal, it doesn't need nohup - it will live until terminated or completed. However many processes try to write to the terminal during execution, and if there is no terminal (e.g. due to logout) they throw a "hangup" signal and die. nohup prevents that, but you can prevent that manually by redirecting all output to file and background it ( command &> file &).
nohup simply automate this process for you.

nohup also prevents kill when input from terminal is missing for same reason, but that usage is much less common (nohup redirects /dev/null to input, instead of terminal/standard input)

Comment: Not true. If the shell receives a SIGHUP, and the backgrounded process is still a job being managed by the shell, that process will also receive a SIGHUP. Also when writing to a terminal which is no longer present you get SIGPIPE, not SIGHUP.

Answer (score -4):

I figured out the solution for remote login:

If the terminal from which the process with nohup has been started and if the terminal has been killed then the process will also keep running. However, if you simply log out with `exit` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> then it doesn't, but the logout will also work if you have logged out of the graphical login.